# Draw on/upon vs draw from

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What are the differences between phrasal verbs Draw on/upon and draw from. They used in academic texts and it seems that their meaning is so close.
for example in the following sentences:

> Sociobiology is a field of biology that aims to examine and explain
>   social behavior in terms of evolution. It **draws from** disciplines
>   including ethology, anthropology, evolution, zoology, archaeology, and
>   population genetics.
>
> Social researchers **draw upon** a variety of qualitative and quantitative
>   techniques.
>
> Many different methodologies are used to study cognitive science. As
>   the field is highly interdisciplinary, research often cuts across
>   multiple areas of study, **drawing on** research methods from psychology,
>   neuroscience, computer science and systems theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Draw on*** and ***draw upon*** I consider absolutely 100% equivalent and interchangeable. This is true in most if not all possible uses of *on* and *upon*, I believe.

In this context, ***draw from*** is also equivalent, as I read it.

However, there are uses for *draw on/upon* in which you can't use *draw from* as an alternative, and vice versa.

> In his attempt to get a prestigious job, he drew upon favours owed to his father by influential men.

This is the same as *drawing upon* an account. In the case of a bank account, we might *withdraw from* the account, or *draw upon* the account - the latter being slightly old fashioned - but we wouldn't *draw from* the account in most situations.

> The membership of the British and Irish Lions is drawn from Welsh, English, Scottish and Irish players.

Essentially, we don't usually use *draw* in this sense, in the past tense (specifically the past participle), with *on* or *upon*. To *draw on* something also means to make markings on it, such as with a pen or a crayon, and *drawn on* will generally refer to that meaning. The preterite (simple past) *drew* does not have this restriction.

Answer (score 1):

There's no glaring difference to me, however if I had to choose then I'd use "draw from" in situations where somebody/something is influenced by others, in this case sociology being influenced by other disciplines.

On the other hand, draws upon would indicate a reliance on, where drawing upon something is summoning it and using it for a purpose, just as scientists draw upon scientific techniques, they rely on them, they do not draw from them.

It is a nuance though!